# Game design and review?

Tags: game-design, game-development

Where is a good place / forum to get new games reviewed & tested by other game developers and avid players?

Answer (score 1):

I've found Playtesting groups through Meetup. Depending on your location someone might be running a local one. Otherwise Boardgamegeeks has a section.